# Get AD Users Visual Studio Web App versus Console

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

I have the following code below.

- When I run Debug in Visual Studio with this code in an ASP.NET Core App (so running as IIS Express) this works
- When I run Debug in Visual Studio with this code in a ASP.NET hosted process in a Windows Service this return nothing, but also no error messages

I connect from my home laptop via RDP to another laptop where VPN is running, so I think that is probably it. I tried running visual studio as admin, running the compiled exe as admin, /runas with the domain specified, etc but the commandline app will show nothing while the asp.net core app shows the list. So it must be the user it runs under.

But when i run  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name in both cases it gives the same domain and name (me).  In task manager the devenv and iis process is me.

```
        public List<AdSecurityGroupDTO> GetAllDomainSecurityGroups(string domain)
    {
        List<AdSecurityGroupDTO> result = new List<AdSecurityGroupDTO>();
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            GroupPrincipal findAllGroups = new GroupPrincipal(ctx, " * ");
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(findAllGroups);
            foreach (Principal group in ps.FindAll())
            {
                AdSecurityGroupDTO adSecurityGroupDTO = new();
                adSecurityGroupDTO.Name = group.Name;
                adSecurityGroupDTO.Description = group.Description;
                adSecurityGroupDTO.DisplayName = group.DisplayName;
                adSecurityGroupDTO.DistinguishedName = group.DistinguishedName;
                adSecurityGroupDTO.SamAccountName = group.SamAccountName;
                result.Add(adSecurityGroupDTO);
            }                
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A service must be run from within the context of the Services Control Manager rather than from within Visual Studio.You can check this:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications)

Comment: I changed the code to use an ldap query with the same domain and then it works. So I think it is the behavior of the classes.